# Jasper Reports : How to suppress a footer completely after 1st page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have designed a jasper report in iReports. My requirement is to show the footer only on the first page. I have put a boolean condition on the footer band to show it only on the 1st page but still after doing this, footer section takes a blank space in each page.

How to suppress a footer completely after 1st page ???

BR
Majid

Answer (score 3):

you can use printWhenExpression , and evaluate to true when pageCount = 1 , pageCount is an implicit parameter available in jasperreport.

Comment: Hope you meant implicit variable PAGE_COUNT.
It is not working with the implicit variable PAGE_COUNT. The page footer spacing is still there in the report when the PAGE_COUNT added in the printWhen expression, the only change is the page footer data won't display when the condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

U can Use `printWhenExpression` attribute. This would print the elements only if its evaluated to true and u can use pageCount expression here